# How to pass an XML file through QBXMLRP2

Tags: xml, qbxml

I am new in developing an app to import invoices into QB.
I have installed the SDK3.0 and I try to use the sample file "AddInvoiceSpecifyTemplate".
It connects to QB but when I proceed, I get an error:
"Cannot find .../ProgramFiles(x86)/Intuit/IDN/QBSDK13.0... Make sure the path or INternet address is correct"
I look inside the sample file and it says:

"This xml file will only work when passed through the QBXMLRP2 request processor. The QBXMLRP request processor does not support SDK 3.0 version messages."

How do I pass the file through the QBXMLRP2?

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 3 of the QBSDK Programmer's Guide talks about how to connect.  There are examples for several programming languages.  I use WinDev and connect just fine but the examples do not pertain perfectly.